# Assets not loaded for a mounted Sinatra app with thin and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, sinatra, resque

I have a simple Rails app with Resque server mounted in `routes.rb` as

```
require 'resque/server'
require 'resque_scheduler'


    MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

        authenticate :user do
            mount Resque::Server.new, :at => "/tasks"
        end
        ...
        ...
```

Mounted the app in routes to use devise based authentication. In production however, the assets are not loaded for the Resque server while the assets for the main Rails app load properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around this worked for me with nginx and thin:

```
require 'resque/server'

class SecuredResqueServer < Resque::Server
  set :static, true
  set :root, Resque::Server.root
end
```

The routes file look as follows:

```
    require 'resque/server'
    require 'resque_scheduler'
    require './app/secured_resque_server'


    MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    ...
    ...
    authenticate :user do
        mount SecuredResqueServer.new, :at => "/tasks"
    end
    ...
    ...
```

and changing

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

in production.rb to

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

Thirdly, in some cases nginx is configured for rails as follows:

```
server{
        ...
        ...
        location ~*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|js)$ {
                root /PATH_TO_APP/public;
        }
        ...
        ...
      }
```

Where **PATH_TO_APP** is the path of the application root directory. Such location declaration prevents assets to be loaded from any other location for a mounted rake app or engine. This therefore, needs to be removed/commented out.

Lastly, don't forget to do a `Ctrl+F5` to force reload the page :)